# Add list to fragment without extending ListFragment

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I am trying to add a `ListView` using `Fragment`. I know that it can be done by extending `ListFragment` and so on. But I want to extend `Fragment` and then add `listView`. But the following code is not working ( its not showing any errors too).

Fragment class

```
public class OtherFragment extends Fragment { 

    final String[] items = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
       "Linux", "OS/2" };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {       
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container,false);
        ListView list = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

XML file for fragment

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity ( Main class)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
        if(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContent)==null)
        {
            Log.d("add fragment", "fragment added");
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragmentContent, new OtherFragment());
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml ( main xml file)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContent"
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fixed:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Ugly mistake. Thanks nininho

Comment: This is wrong android:layout_width="0px", should be match_parent.

Comment: The preferred method is to use android:layout_width="0dp" and then add android:layout_weight="some number"

Comment: @nininho thanx. LOL me. I think eclipse gave some suggestion somewhere and then I copied it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Your Main Activity needs to extend a FragmentActivity not just Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

And your layout needs to be a Fragment not a linear layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <Fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContent"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am adding fragment dynamically, so I don't think I need to add fragment tag in xml file.

Comment: That is fine, but you still need to extend the FragmentActivity.

Comment: Have you read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Ugly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `LisFragment` , this will avoid other problems in the future. some thing like if you opened fragment above normal fragment with list view, you face some problems with onCLick handling